# How to get unsampled data from Google Analytics API in a specific day

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am building a package that uses the Google Analytics API for Python.

But, in severous cases when I have multiple dimensions the extraction by day is sampled.

I know that if I use sampling_level = LARGE will use a sample more accurate.

But, somebody knows if has a way to reduce a request that you can extract one day without sampling?

Grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting sampling to LARGE is the only method we have to decide the amount of sampling but as you already know this doesn't prevent it.

The only way to reduce the chances of sampling is to request less data. A reduced number of dimensions and metrics as well as a shorter date range are the best ways to ensure that you dont get sampled data

Comment: Oh, this is really sad.

Will be magic if someday they fix that and create a solution for these cases.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this something that will be fix I believe it is working as intended

Answer (score 1):

there are several tactics of building unsampled reports, most popular is splitting your report into shorter time ranges up to hours. Mark Edmondson did a great work on anti-sampling in his R package so you might find it useful. You may start with this blog post https://code.markedmondson.me/anti-sampling-google-analytics-api/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you want to hear but, one way of getting unsampled data from Google analytics is to use [unsampled reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2601061). However this requires that you sign up for [Google Marketing Platform](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/analytics-360/features/). With these you can create an unsampled report request using the [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/unsampled-reports) or the UI.

There is also a way to export the [data to Big Query](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en). But you lose the analysis that Google provides and will have to do that yourself. This too requires that you sign up for Google Marketing Platform.